# Corona - Move Groups with transition.to

Tags: performance, coronasdk, transition, game-engine

I want to move my main group of objects at different speeds.

I can move my group all at same speed no problem, and ad to a var for deletion as required. But how would I get the objects to move at different speeds, without a for loop and looking into the group itself, because if I use a for loop then will need multiple vars to hold the "tween" references ...

```
local transOptions = { 
                time = math.abs(distanceToMaxLeft / speedToMove), 
                x = BG_MIN_X_POS, 
                onComplete = cancelAnyExistingTransition(bg) 
            };
bg.tween = transition.to(mainSceneGroup, transOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about accessing objects using mainSceneGroup[ObjectIndex] ?